# HTML php localhost database retrieval

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was trying to get data from the database but it won't display correctly.

Note: I used old project file I did back in college prev semester which is working. But implementation on the new project won't work. How can I fix the issue? The table is shown but the data are not fetched correctly

What I am using:

- Notepad+
- wamp

things i tried:

- used different methods (from google, stackoverflow, w3school) non of them work
- changed server name to localhost:8082 (since this is how my link look like http://localhost:8082/phpmyadmin)

[the results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spn6j.png)

the code

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "somepass";
$dbname = "gamewebsitedatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    
}
$result = $conn->query("select weapon_icon, weapon_name,weapon_type,weapon_rarity from weapons");

?>
<table align="center">
        <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>rarity</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='".$row['weapon_icon']."' width=199 height=188 />";
            echo "<td>".$row["weapon_name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["weapon_type"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row["weapon_rarity"]."</td>";

            
        
            echo "</table>";
            }
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to close the first `<td>` (with the image inside), might that be the issue? You should probably also move the `</table>` one line down, outside of the loop

Comment: What OS -- Windows? Linux? To specify the port -- the ":2082" in your example, you need to make the hostname = "127.0.0.1" and at the end of the mysql_connect, add the port as an additional parameter: mysql_connected(host, name, pwd, db, port).

Comment: Could you explain better what you mean by "not fetched correctly"?

Comment: @chrki thats help remove last part of error

Comment: @mrunion i am using windows, and it wont work when i tried to add port still same issue

Comment: @FelippeDuarte database result wont appear https://i.stack.imgur.com/spn6j.png

Comment: It seems that you don't have the PHP installed and/or configured with your web server.

Comment: What is the exact error message you see?

Comment: Looks like your PHP code isn't actually being executed, how are you visiting the page? The filename should end in `.php`, for example `http://localhost:8082/something.php`

Comment: @chrki yes indeed i saved the file again as php and work perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your database makeup; your server must run PHP and the user must have access to read the database; your environment must be setup properly in order to execute. I quickly dumped some data on my end by modifying your code a little on a dummy DB:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "somepass";
$dbname = "gamewebsitedatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}

$q = "select * from weapons";
$result = $conn->query($q);

?>
<table align="center">
        <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>rarity</th>

        </tr>
        <?php

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='".$row['weapon_icon']."' width=199 height=188 /></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["weapon_name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["weapon_type"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["weapon_rarity"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
?>
```

Keep in mind you were using mysqli_fetch_array($result); I swapped it to $result->fetch_assoc() as I want to loop through the associated records in my select statement. I also modified select to select all (*) in my environment; doesn't make a difference much from what you had if you elect specific columns you can select just those;

You had an unclosed Table Row tag also; I've modified for you by ending the  properly; a row per result. :)

The image you posted as a result looked as if PHP wasn't even functioning and everything came through as text; just verify your PHP version and of course the credetials of the user and database.

I ran this localhost on a linux based machine with PHP5; if you can run PHP on your server; and your username is indeed privilaged to read the data and connect; you should be able to get this code working for you.

Hope it helps!